# SQL server 2016 clustered column store index with Top clause

Tags: indexing, sql-server-2016, columnstore

Am trying to **select top N** rows from table with clustered columns store index in sql server 2016 it takes more time(more than minute) to return data.

when I remove Top and say **select * from** data is returned in less than 5 seconds. [Plan with TOP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8wnl.png)

[Plan without TOP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eG34F.png)

[XML Plan with top`Select with top on clustered column store index`](https://pastebin.com/RfSY47WF)

[XML Plan without top](https://pastebin.com/U8ntGXWC)

Comment: I would take a look at the query execution plan

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be
reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post
code samples of what you have done 
(i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Comment: added execution plan for both with top and without top